# VSCode SCM tab suddenly disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

I must have pressed a wrong combination of keys with my crooked fingers which caused the version control tab to disappear from the sidebar.

Then I found source control tab somewhere in VSCode, dragged it into the sidebar, it shows the changes, however, the icon is completely different and also it doesn't show the number of current changes.

What happened?
In the below screenshot the yellow icon is what I have for SCM now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 1.46 it is now possible to [drag and drop panels and views](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_flexible-layout)

If a panel/view is not in a spot you want and you want it back in its original place you can **Right Click** on the panel/view header and choose **Reset Location**.

Answer (score 48):

I had to use the **View: Reset View Locations** command to solve this problem in Visual Studio Code version 1.47 (macOS - Catalina).

To do this, just press `Cmd`+`Shift`+`P` (macOS) or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P` (Linux/Windows), type `workbench.action.resetViewLocations`, then press `Enter`.

[Release notes - May 2020 (version 1.46)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_flexible-layout)

Comment: I love you @rafaelfpereira. I was using the circleci extension, and had placed it side-by-side with the terminal. Then I removed it from there, and it disappeared. 20 google searches later, I end up here, and the only thing that worked was your solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: i had hopes that this would work..but to no avail. strangely i see down below at the lower left it shows 'master*' as my repo. so it knows my code is sourced in git.  just not seeing that tab on the left anymore

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure what you actually dragged to the activity bar vscode is really modular in this way; hard to say without being there, but you can re-enable SCM button.

Even if you use the short cut to open the source control view (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, it will disappear again after you focus out of it (when it's not enabled).

[image]

To re-enable it, right-click anywhere on the Activity Bar and select 'Source Control'

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As @rioV8 commented - what solved it for me was to right click on the icon and click "Reset Location"

Answer (score 3):

Try right clicking on the bar and you should see a menu like the one below

[image: right click menu]

recheck the source control and the icon should appear.

Answer (score 1):

If the "Source Control" panel is not on the side/activity bar or dissapeared for some reason, you check it on the "Explorer" panel. If you don't see it on the Explorer list, you can find it on the top right menu of the explorer panel. You can just check it and then it appears on the Explorer panel list.

[image]

Then you can just **drag** the Source Control panel and **drop** it on the side/activity bar. It gets back to its original place.

[image]

Finally!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For people who applied the methods above but still could not see the source control panel where you could jump to editted files quickly but only the side bar, here is the way you can fix it:

After you have got the source control panel appeared, right click **any available tabs you have inside the panel**, such as `commits`, `file history`, `branches` etc. Then make sure you chose the `Source Control`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of vscode v1.75 you can reset **all** the view locations from the Layout Control button near the upper right:

[image: reset view location defaults]

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Code version 1.76.1 this problem can be resolved by:

- Ctrl-shift-g (show source control)
- Right click the source control tab
- From the popup menu choose 'Keep source control'