# Visual Studio code activity bar - Missing changed files tab

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

The changed files tab in VS Code Activity bar is missing.

**Changed files tab**

[image]

**My current activity bar** is as below.

[image]

Its showing the search and pending changes together. What should I do to get my changed files tab back?

**VS Code version:** 1.74.3

**Operating System:** Windows 10

Comment: I don't know why this question is being requested to close under "Not about programming or software development" category. This is also related to software development. This platform is not just for asking coding related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a panel is not in a spot you want and you want it back in its original place you can **right click** on the panel/view header and choose **Reset Location**.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62855637/vscode-scm-tab-suddenly-disappeared#:%7E:text=If%20the%20%22Source%20Control%22%20panel,on%20the%20Explorer%20panel%20list.) for more solutions.

Also, View: Reset View Locations command to solve this problem in Visual Studio Code version 1.47 (macOS - Catalina).

To do this, just press Cmd+Shift+P (macOS) or Ctrl+Shift+P (Linux/Windows), type workbench.action.resetViewLocations, then press Enter.