# Why can't VSCode visualize `git` differences from files on a shared drive?

Tags: visual-studio-code, shared-drive

I use VSCode for editing files both on my local drive and on a shared drive. However, I've noticed that VSCode frequently does not visualize the `diff`s for files on the shared drive. Is this a known issue? How can I troubleshoot this?

I've tried restarting VSCode, and the [Git built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70296872/5478086) to no avail.

Let me know if there's any environment or system specifications I can share here to shed more light.

Comment: Are you "sharing" the .git folder on the shared drive??

Comment: @topsail I think so, because the files appear under the source control tab. Also, when I do `git status` from macOS, I get some output. I also just noticed that when I do `git diff HEAD:filea filea`, where `filea` is a file I didn't modify, it shows the entire file in red (`-`), and then the entire file again in green (+). In this Git difference the only difference is that each line has a `^M` character at the end of each line. Continued in second comment -->

Comment: `^M` probably represents a carriage return here. But you really cannot just put a git repository on a shared drive and then actually share the entire repository as such. What you can do is put a bare git repository on a shared drive. Then different people can clone it and push/pull etc. -- but each person needs to have their own "local" repository.

Comment: @topsail If I do `git diff HEAD:fileb fileb`, where `fileb` is a file I did modify by adding and removing lines, it shows the original file all in red (-), and the new version all in green (+). In the new version each line has been appended with a `^M` character. According to this Unix.SE post's comments and answer, it seems that `^M` was introduced at some point. But I can't tell if it's VSCode or Git that's doing it, and how to fix it.

Comment: Its possible that git saves EOL in LF format, then restores them when you checkout. Main problem -- see above. Are you working with other people with this repo? It should be a bare repository and then you all separately clone it and work in your own local repositories (this is basically how github and other git servers work).

Comment: @topsail I'm looking into the solutions proposed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/make-git-diff-ignore-m).

Comment: Yes you can configure git to store line endings `as-is` ... but I advise to to be careful. You cannot share a git repository on shared drive - each different person should be working on a local repository cloned from a shared (bare!) repository.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `git config --global core.autocrlf true`. This is a possible duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889559/make-git-diff-ignore-m).

I'm answering my own question starting with a correction. I thought was VSCode not visualizing differences because I saw files in the source control tab, with the "M" tag, but didn't see any `diff` highlighting (e.g., green, or red). But in reality VSCode was not wrong, because the diff was just one character, `^M`. I realized this when I did `git diff HEAD:filea filea` and noticed the entire file was red (-) and again in green (+). The difference between the original and new versions was that each line was appended with a `^M` character.

According to this [Unix.SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it) the `^M` character appears when files originating from Windows systems are read by Unix-like systems. My files are originating from a shared drive, which may or may not be Windows-based.

I troubleshooted by situation further by using `git diff HEAD:fileb fileb`, where `fileb` is a file I had modified, and again the entire original file was in red (-) and the new version was in green (+), including the `^M` characters. When I ran `git diff --ignore-cr-at-eol HEAD:fileb fileb` it showed the correct highlighting, with only the deleted parts in red (-) and the added parts in green (+).

Although this fixed everything on the command life for `git`, VSCode was still tracking the files as modified. However, when I ran `git config --global core.autocrlf true`, then all the files that were being tracked just for the `^M` characters were removed from the version control tab. Note, however, that before changing git `config` I tried to fix the files manually by changing the EOL on VSCode from "CRLF" to "LF", and this change was reflected on the `git` command line but not VSCode. Only changing Git's `config` fixed the issue on the command line and on VSCode.